# OpenAM Tomcat J2EE Agent Configuration For Authorization

Tags: tomcat, authorization, policy, opensso, openam

I'd like to configure authorization into a test webapp staged in Tomcat 6 using OpenAM.  The ultimate goal/use case would something like:

- user bob belongs to group employee
- user john belongs to group manager
- only employees and managers can access the employee.jsp page
- only managers can access the manager.jsp page

I find plenty of documentation on the authentication piece and have that configured properly in my environment.
Before logging in, I can access 'public' pages (not enforced uri's I've configured), but as soon as I try to access a protected page like "employee.jsp", I get redirected to OpenAM's login module and have to authenticate.  I can authenticate as a bob who belongs to the group employee (the backing user store is an active directory), but after the redirect I still get access denied.  How can I configure access for this?  The policy agent deployed for protecting this resource is a j2ee_agent.  The web agent seems more relevant, but I gathered that j2ee agents are deployed for Tomcat.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Environment:

- webapp deployed in tomcat 6 staged on Windows 2008 server, with AD
- j2ee policy agent deployed in same tomcat 6 instance with configuration centralized in server
- openam server on a separate linux box deployed within jboss 7, using the Windows 2008 Server AD as user store.

Answer (score 3):

The J2EE agent support J2EE policy. In the data store used by OpenAM you have to assign the group to the users of your choice.

OpenAM will abstract from that 'data store group' and build and 'OpenAM group'.

You have to configure a mapping for this 'OpenAM group' to your J2EE roles in the deployment container specific deployment descriptor.

J2EE Agent mode should be  'J2EE_POLICY' or 'ALL' (latter mandates configuration of url policies in OpenAM).

You may look into the agentsample web-app delivered with the J2EE agent.

Also the agent debug log (level set to 'message') would tell you if and how the mapping is done.